# Google Apps Script Basecamp POST

Tags: api, google-apps-script, basecamp

I've tried all the combinations I can think of to make this work. What do I need to send to the New Basecamp API as a `POST` field to have it accept my POST data?

My code is:

```
function getFilterBy() {
    var url = "https://basecamp.com/****/api/v1/projects/*****.json";
    var payload =  {"name" : "myapp", "description" : "no desc mls"};
    var opt = {
               "contentType" : "application/json",
               "method" : "POST",
               "headers":{ "User-Agent": "myapp (user@somewhere.com)",
                           "Authorization" :"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("user" + ":" + "pass")},
               "validateHttpsCertificates" :false,
               "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
               "payload" : payload
               };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
    var text = response.getContentText();
    Logger.log(text);
    }
```

My Error is:

```
lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   description=no+desc+mls&name=Ho
                 (right here) ------^
```

I have tried to `Utilities.jsonStringify`, but no luck. I know its a noob error, but I just can't figure it out. If there is a place you are aware of where I can get this info too that would be phenomenal.

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1**

```
function getFilterBy() {
       var url = "https://basecamp.com/****/api/v1/projects/****.json";
       var payload =  {name : 'myApp Change'};
       var opt = {
                   "contentType" : "application/json",
                   "method" : "POST",
                   "headers":{ "User-Agent": "myApp (user@ex.com)",
                   "Authorization" :"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode("user" + ":" + "pass")},
                   "validateHttpsCertificates" :false,
                   "muteHttpExceptions" : true,
                   "payload" : Utilities.jsonStringify(payload)
                    };
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
        var text = response.getContentText();
        Logger.log(text);
        }
```

**Yields Err:**

```
<body>
    <div class="dialog">
     <div class="innercol">
       <h1>Hmm, that isn&rsquo;t right</h1>
       <h2>You may have typed the URL incorrectly.</h2>
       <p>Check to make sure you&rsquo;ve got the spelling, capitalization, etc. exactly right.</p>
     </div>
    </div>
    <p id="back" class="back">
      <a href="javascript:window.history.back();">&larr; Back to previous page</a>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.history.length <= 1) document.getElementById("back").style.display = "none";
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you tried with JSON.stringify correctly? This example here correctly creates a project for me in Basecamp with the specifified project name/description in the POST payload.

Note, I wrote this quickly to not include the UserAgent - you'll want to put that back in.

```
function createProject() { 
  var user = 'USERNAME';
  var password = 'PASSWORD'
  var accoundId = 'ACCOUNTID#';

  var url = 'https://basecamp.com/'+accoundId+'/api/v1/projects.json';  
  var payload =  {name : 'new project', description : 'my project description'};
  var opt = {
    contentType : 'application/json',
    method : 'post',
    headers:{Authorization :"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + password)},
    validateHttpsCertificates :false,
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    payload : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
  var text = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(text);
}
```

In order to update a project, you have to use the `put` verb instead of `post` as [documented](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/projects.md#update-project) here

Here is a working sample -

```
function updateProject() { 
  var projectId = '2413370';
  var url = 'https://basecamp.com/'+accoundId+'/api/v1/projects/'+projectId+'.json';  
  var payload =  {name : 'new project', description : 'my new new project description'};
  var opt = {
    contentType : 'application/json',
    method : 'put',
    headers:{Authorization :"Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + password)},
    validateHttpsCertificates :false,
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
    payload : JSON.stringify(payload)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opt);
  var text = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(text);
}
```

Comment: That does work to create a new project but not to edit an existing project for some reason.

Comment: You shouldn't get the error you specified if that is the case. Do you get a different error - it shouldn't be regarding "invalid char in json text".

Comment: Updated the sample code. You need to use "put" vs. "post". That's standard REST convention to update a resource .

Comment: That's embarassing. Thankyou.

Comment: No worries. You might want to use a standalone REST tool like this for Chrome browser - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en to test out all your individual communications before moving that flow into Apps Script. That way you can decompose your Apps Script logic (if any) with standard REST questions.